# Datagridview - suspend row filtering / refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have table like this:

name | number 
CBC  |   5 
CBA  |   3 
CAB  |   6

and set row filter:

```
(table.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = " number > 0  and name like 'C%' ";
```

is possible to suspend filtering or stop refresh table (for a while) to see for example:

name | number 
CBC  |   5 
CBA  |   0 
CAB  |   6

when i manualy change 3 to 0?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting exactly? The way I read your question atm is that you want a filtered table that stops filtering during manual updates (I speculate doing so will reveal previously filtered entries btw), then resume filtering when the edit is finished.

Comment: exactly what you say - stop filtering when user manualy update row in table

Comment: In my test example with your filter applied, the filter only applies to the manually 0'd out row once you leave edit mode (tab-, Enter-, arrow-out of the editing cell). If this isn't the desired behavior, I've misunderstood.

Comment: this is not desired behavior - I need to see this 0 after change but filter hides them....

Comment: @areklipno I am wondering if you have managed to find the solution of your issue? Please advise thanks.

Comment: no... i don't found solution...

Answer (score 0):

I found way to workaround this trouble:

I add column add my table is:

```
id | name | number
1  | CBC  | 5
2  | CBA  | 3
3  | CAB  | 6
```

and code to freeze result what i want is:

```
(table.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = " number > 0  and name like 'C%' ";

string ids;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in table.Rows)
 {
     if (row.Visible)
     {
        if (ids.Length > 2)
        {
          ids = ids + " or ";
        }
        ids = id + " id = '"+row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString()+"' ";
     }
 }

(table.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = ids;
```